# How to format a Windows Forms Textbox with thousand separator and decimal separtor for numeric input

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting

I'm new to Windows Forms and try to do something. I'm using C#.

I'm using Windows Forms and I've put eight textboxes on my form, and all are numeric with decimal value.

I like to achieve the results below. My decimal separator is a comma and thousand separator is a dot.
I've ever seen something like ##.###,## or whatever, but don't remember....  How can i achieve the below approach?

So the idea is when I type 1234 and leave the focus from the textbox it should format and when I get in the textbox back again the thousand separator should not format only the decimal separator.

I think I've to use some events like LostFocus.

**Input                 Result**

1234                1.234,00

12.34                    12,34

12,34                    12,34

1234567     1.234.567,00

12,34                    12,34

12345,67     12.345,67

Comment: This is non-standard formatting. To achieve what you want you will have to run your input values (`string`s or numeric values) through your own formatting method. The reason for this is that you require custom behaviour which changes based on the input values in a non-standard way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On your LostFocus event in the textbox, use:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
```

Make sure that the text is double / integer first before applying the above logic or it will throw an exception. This solution is rather harsh, tough.

If you want the format to be in a specific culture rather than your current computer's culture, then

```
textBox1.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID"), "{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
```

The above example is for the Indonesian currency format, in which the thousand separator use dot (".") rather than comma (",").

Comment: it's not working, after entering any value and leaving the textbox it shows : #,##0

Comment: with the ne format: 
1145  becomes 1,145 and 11.45 becomes 11 and 50 remains 50

Comment: Oh I have updated my answer again. Did not see your requirement of trailing zero

Comment: exact what I need just 1 thing 1) in your code thousand separator is a comma it should be a dot AND decimal is dot it should be a comma... your code: 1,145.00 it should be 1.145,00

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use the [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).

You could adjust the mask based on the input length when losing focus.

Comment: I tried maskedtextbox, with 999.999,99 and 000.000,00  but there is no freedom then and I have to put a number with 9 Masker or a space for 0 masker to just achieve 1,25.

Comment: It might work if you remove the mask on Enter, then on Leave, check the length and apply a Mask.