# Make thousands separator on a TextBox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Is there any way to make thousands separator on a TextBox in visual basic? Pls tel me what are the ways are there? I say lot of thanks in advance..

Comment: This question explains very well how to do it in C#. The process is exactly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473216/how-to-format-a-windows-forms-textbox-with-thousand-separator-and-decimal-separt

Comment: maskedtextbox will be easier .. http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/maskedtextbox-control-in-vb.net1

Comment: What sort of variable(integer, double, etc.) are you trying to show in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a textbox, I would suggest also validating the users input. Here's a simple validation method that will also format the string with 2 decimal places and thousands separator:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Try
        TextBox1.Text = FormatNumber(TextBox1.Text, 2, TriState.False, , TriState.True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Only digits and/or a decimal please.")
        e.Cancel = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

If the string in the textbox, when it loses focus, can be parsed to a number it will be formatted.  If not a messagebox notifying the user of the error is displayed and the focus returns to the textbox.

MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the validating event

MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the Try...Catch...Finally Statement

MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatnumber%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on FormatNumber

Hard to see how one would get millions of strings input into a single line textbox, but here is another way:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
   If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, vbNull) Then
       TextBox1.Text = FormatNumber(TextBox1.Text, 2, TriState.False, , TriState.True)
   Else
       MessageBox.Show("Only digits and/or a decimal please.")
       e.Cancel = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use one of the TryParse methods instead of a Try-Catch.

Comment: If you were parsing millions of strings with a lot of 'numeric' errors you would see a huge difference.  Try-Catch shouldn't be used to test the validity of whether a string can be converted to a number.  It is a bad habit to use Try-Catch like this.  From MSDN, "Use a Try…Catch statement only to signal the occurrence of unusual or unanticipated program events."  Certainly garbage input from users is not unusual or unanticipated.

Answer (score -1):

**The laziest way to put thousands separator on a TextBox in visual basic**

1. **Right click** on the TextBox .
2. Go to **properties**.
3. Search for ThousandsSeparat and set to **true**.

Hope it help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRMOV.png)