# InputScope digits dot default

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When I use such Xaml:

```
<TextBox ..... InputScope="Digits" />
```

I can see "dot" on bottom of numerical keyboard.
But sometimes, I can see "comma" instead of "dot".

When I see "comma" I have to hold on button to choose "dot". 
How can I configure TextBox to have "dot" by default all the time?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it depends on the current **CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator** value only, thus in different regions its different one.

Thus I would suggest looking for a workarounds like [one suggested in earlier question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473216/how-to-format-a-windows-forms-textbox-with-thousand-separator-and-decimal-separt), or use custom input boxes, like I did for [Lat/lon values](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Implementing_numerical_InputBox_in_Windows_Phone)